# Windows 10 snap window to 3/4th of screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-snap-assist

I am using windows 10 pro.

I can snap windows to the half of my screen by doing `ctrl + right arrow` or `ctrl + left arrow`.

And this is great but what if I want to snap a window to the 3/4th of right and another on the 1/4th of left.

Creating software I have a widescreen and have debug tools running which I want on the smaller side.

Let me know If I can hack my way into doing this or not.

Thanks

Comment: Windows itself can’t do that. However, when both sides of the screen have snapped windows, you can move the divider. Perhaps that’s enough?

Comment: Yes, I know about doing that. But wished there was a way I could define the separator.